# Invalid Executable - The executable ProjectName WatchKit Extension' does not contain bitcode

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, watchkit, apple-watch, watch

I have been trying to submit my watch app in the app store but It's been rejected due to the following reason.

Invalid Executable - The executable 'ProjectName.app/Watch/ProjectName WatchKit App.app/PlugIns/ProjectName WatchKit Extension.appex/ProjectName WatchKit Extension' does not contain bitcode

I have enabled the bitcode of all the targets except the Test target.
Also i don't see any bitcode related settings in the target for watchExtension.
I have strolled through many links but didn't find any concrete solution as yet.

Any help would be highly appreciated. Thank you so much in advance :)

Comment: I have a same issue. Any solution

Comment: Does this answer your question? [WatchOS App for React-Native IOS app is not uploading to App Store Connect (ITMS-90496: Invalid Executable)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70120902/watchos-app-for-react-native-ios-app-is-not-uploading-to-app-store-connect-itms)